# While adding connectivity_plus: ^4.0.1 in flutter project, app is not installing in device

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to add connectivity_plus: ^4.0.1 package in flutter app but when I add this package in yaml file then app stop installing in device. otherwise it runs perfectly. Is there something I am missing? My yaml file looks like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
  http: ^0.13.6  
  connectivity_plus: ^4.0.1
```

Comment: please mention the error message 
( while you tried to install with the connectivity_plus: ^4.0.1 package )

Comment: There is no error message. package is installed but when I run application(F5) it just dont get installed on physical mobile device. And when I remove package, application runs successfully.